# Initialize Activity For Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am unit testing an `Activity`.

```
private MyActivity _controller;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    ShadowLog.stream = System.out;

    _controller = Mockito.spy(new MyActivity());
}
```

However when I go to test it:

```
@Test
public void testInitRoot() throws Exception
{
    _controller.initRoot();
}
```

I get a crash:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:135)

After research I believe this is because the context is null and it can't properly get resources.

My question is: how do I actually create an `Activity` object for the sole purpose of testing? I run in Robolectric so I'm not looking to use `Intent` and `startActivity`. I'm looking for something like

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity(validContext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Robolectric.setupActivity()` to start your activity.

```
private MyActivity mActivity;
mActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
```